# Error when running onEdit(e) to fire for specific sheet range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I need to limit the function `onEdit()` to fire only when changes are made within the specific range. Users selects a value in column B and column A is opopulated with a specific value.
Although the funciton below seems to work as desired, when run from within the Apps Editor, it throws an error:
*`TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined.`*

which apparently refers to `e.source.getSheetName` line

```
function onEdit(e) {

  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "Activity" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 2 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 2 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 2 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 100
  ) {
    e.value !=='' ? e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(caseID()) : null
    };
  };
```

I am not sure if this could be ignored, since the function works *(inserts result of caseID function in column A, when value is changed in column B)*?
Thank you in advance,

Comment: `e` is `undefined` because there's no edit event(because there was no edit). See view> Executions for the actual error. There's also no `getSheetName()` method in spreadsheet class. The for-loop, ss, range and activity are unnecessary.

Comment: @TheMaster `getSheetName()` What about here: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetname)

Comment: @TheMaster Have updated the code, removed `ss, activity, range` and `for`-loop - thank you!

Comment: Yes. It seems there's that method. But I presume that that method will only provide the first sheet's name instead of the edited sheet's name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I test a trigger function in GAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16089041/how-can-i-test-a-trigger-function-in-gas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer :** I guess, we can ignore that for now.

**Reason :** When we run that function manually in Apps Editor we don't pass the event object. So that's why it's giving `e` as `undefined` error.

I guess we can interpret running that function manually as running `onEdit()` whereas function signature required argument `e`. So that's why `e` is undefined when executed manually.

But when it's triggered due to edit in sheet, then that event object is passed to the function as argument and hence it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I believe getSheetName() only returns the first sheet's name instead of the edited sheet's name. To get the correct edited sheet name, you should first get the sheet and then it's name. Also, this is preferably done from the range rather than the source:

```
e.range.getSheet().getName() === "Activity"
```

Comment: Regarding this line of code: `e.value !=='' ? e.range.offset(0,-1).setValue(caseID()) : null` - how do I clear the value in column A if user delets the value in coumn B?